# What does this while(true) loop do in Arduino or any other language?

Tags: arduino

[image: picture]

In this picture, we have a program that will set up the Arduino to get its IP address. But what does the `while(true)` loop do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It waits forever, because it couldn't get the IP address. Basically, the program gives up and stalls. Nothing happens after this.

Answer (score -3):

It keeps looping till the network interface is initialized.

Comment: I don't really understand how it loops to initialized the network interface.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: See dda's response.  The program just stalls on this line.